# How can I pass an environment variable to a script?

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables

Okay, I can display an environmental variable from the commandline:

`echo $COLUMNS`

And get a response.

But I can't execute that from within a shell script, I get nothing.  So, there must be a way to import that environment variable - but I've not been able to find a simple solution/explanation.

Once upon a time I recall seeing something like `$ENV_COLUMNS`, but that's not correct (or is missing something).

I'm trying for something like this:

```
    for x in $COLUMNS
     do echo -n "-"
    done
    echo #to get the /n
```

Comment: all shell scripts will understand the environment variables by default.... which shell are you using to run this? go and set env in the corresponding rc file

Comment: @anon3202, please join this site and post as a registered user to make the discussion more fruitful.  I've just mistenkenly rejected an anonymous edit probably from you...

Answer (score 12):

You should do:

```
COLUMNS=$COLUMNS my_script
```

You could also do something like this rewrite in `sed`:

```sh
 STTY=
 for fd in 0 1 2
 do      [ -t "$fd" ]    &&
         break
 done|| ${STTY:?Run "$0" on a terminal}
 STTY=$( stty -a <&"$fd" |
         sed     -Ee'/;/{s/^/;/' \
                 -e's/((; *[^ ;]* )[= ]*)?([^;])/\2\\\3/g' \
                 -e's/; *([^ ;]+) ([^;]*)/\n\1=\2/g' \
                 -e's/;* *$//;t' -e\} \
                 -e'H;$!d;x;s/[[:space:]]+/,/g' \
                 -e's/^,*/FLAGS=/;s/,*$//')
```

On my machine *(on this terminal)* that puts the following value in `$STTY`:

```sh
speed=\3\8\4\0\0\ \b\a\u\d
rows=\4\3
columns=\1\0\9
line=\0

intr=\^\C
quit=\^\\
erase=\^\H
kill=\^\U
eof=\^\D
eol=\<\u\n\d\e\f\>

eol2=\<\u\n\d\e\f\>
swtch=\<\u\n\d\e\f\>
start=\^\Q
stop=\^\S
susp=\^\Z
rprnt=\^\R

werase=\^\W
lnext=\^\V
discard=\^\O
min=\1
time=\0
FLAGS=-parenb,-parodd,-cmspar,cs8,-hupcl,-cstopb,cread,-clocal,-crtscts,-ignbrk,-brkint,-ignpar,-parmrk,-inpck,-istrip,-inlcr,-igncr,icrnl,ixon,-ixoff,-iuclc,-ixany,-imaxbel,iutf8,opost,-olcuc,-ocrnl,onlcr,-onocr,-onlret,-ofill,-ofdel,nl0,cr0,tab0,bs0,vt0,ff0,isig,icanon,iexten,echo,echoe,echok,-echonl,-noflsh,-xcase,-tostop,-echoprt,echoctl,echoke,-extproc
```

...which should be plenty safe for `eval`, but it may be a little over the top, though.

Answer (score 7):

You might try to

```
export COLUMNS
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/841108) for an explanation.

But you should tell us how is the script called. If it is started by some crontab, it is likely to be executed in an environment without `COLUMNS`. You might use `printenv`  to check.

Answer (score 6):

This is a follow-on to your previous question and we're getting to what it is you want to do.  I'm quite sure others have their own styles for this, but perhaps this will get you started.

```
#!/bin/bash
SCREEN_WIDTH=$(stty size | awk '{print $2}')
echo "$SCREEN_WIDTH"
```

That echo isn't what you are trying to do, just to demonstrate we've put the value somewhere readily accessible.

Answer (score 3):

An environment variable *is* passed to a script. The problem is that [`COLUMNS` is not an environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215584/whats-the-name-of-the-environment-variable-with-current-terminal-width/215798#215798).

From a script, you can call a command such as [`tput`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tput) to retrieve the terminal dimensions.

```
width=$(tput cols)
</dev/zero head -c "$width" | tr '\0' '-'; echo
```

(This script may not be portable beyond Linux.)

Answer (score 1):

So, it appears that `COLUMNS` is not in `env`, so I guess the title of this thread is incorrect, as it's **not** an environment variable?

```
   export COLUMNS
   echo $COLUMNS
```

Does not work.  From the link I gather `export` is to make something available from the parent process to a child process, which is not what I want to do.  Not sure what that suggestion was about, or if I'm misreading/misunderstanding what was being suggested.

`COLUMNS=$COLUMNS my_script`

Results in:

```
   fork: retry: No child processes
   fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And I've not worked my way through the rest of that "over the top" suggestion, as it's about as clear as mud.

```
   screen_width=`stty size | cut -f2 -d " " -`
```

**Is** working, however.  But that only solves the proximate problem, not the actual problem, as there are more things in `set` that I might want to get out - and I don't know the commands for each of them (if they have commands).  Using `cut` instead of `awk` / `sed` / whatever, as I'd like something that's as portable as possible (and I don't know if `stty` is portable, but it's working right now, so I'm crossing my fingers).

I *am* using a while loop, yeah the for loop didn't work out the way I imagined it would, and no `seq` modifier/whatever in my shell.

I'd really like to know *why* I need double parens, but need them I do.

This *"go and set env in the corresponding rc file"*, sounds interesting, but the directions are unclear :)  I'm guessing that means I could add particular variables to the list that `env` pulls up?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 30-second example:

1. Create a file called test.sh
2. Place this inside it

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo $thing
```

3. Run this to make it excitable `chmod +x test.sh`
4. Run the script (you won't see any output, since `$thing` has no value (yet)

```
./test.sh
```

5. Now give it an environment variable and run it again, this time you'll see output

```
thing=something-random ./test.sh
something-random
```

Comment: It seems as if this is already [suggested in another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215608/116858).

Answer (score 0):

Not an direct answer to your question, but ... why don't you pass that as an argument to your script?

```
your_script $COLUMNS
```

where `your_script` would contain code like

```bash
while (( $# ))
do
    echo -n "-"
    shift
done
echo
```

EDIT: After reading Jason's answer, I checked `COLUMNS` value (it is a single value), and in my case seen it is 80, then realize your `for` loop is wrong (my previous script was for a multi-value variable, not a single value variable). Your `for` loop will only run once, if you want to run a `for` loop four times, then you should:

```bash
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
   your stuff here
done
```

But in your case I guess that what you want is something like:

```bash
count=$1
while (( $count ))
do
    echo -n "-"
    count=$(($count-1))
done
```